# Why does a function which returns a reference work when it takes a reference as a parameter in Rust but not without it?

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust and was going through lifetimes concept. I can understand why the below code doesn't work.

```rust
fn something() -> &str {
    let y = "hello";
    &y
}
```

In my understanding, `y` goes out scope once the function returns. So the reference to `y` is invalid.

I am not getting then why does below compile just fine.

```rust
fn something(t: &str) -> &str {
    let y = "2334343";
    &y
}
```

I have introduced an unused reference parameter but still the first scenario above should be valid? `y` goes out of scope once the function ends! How does this compile successfully?

Is it because, the return reference of this function is valid as long as the shortest param reference is valid?

Comment: Note that the error in your first example isn't about returning `y`, but about a missing lifetime for the returned reference. You can fix the first example by adding an explicit `'static` lifetime: `fn something() -> &'static str { … }`.